# How can someone write an "outstanding" paper?

Tags: journals

There are very difficult and well known journals where they demand only **outstanding** work in order to publish them. What characteristics/standards should a submitted work contain in order to be "**outstanding**"??

Comment: The major characteristic is to be considered outstanding by the editor and referees...

Comment: What are the criteria of the editor and the referees to say: "Ok, this work is outstanding, I will accept it"...? What they search/see on the work?

Comment: Is it a significant result (compare with what the journal usually publishes). Does it open up a whole new area? Is it clearly written so most readers of the journal would recognize the importance? Does it solve some long-standing problem? Is it likely to get 1000 citations? Do we just think it is a cool paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a journal has too-high standards it would be very thin and only publish rarely. That is seldom a good business plan. The standards are as high as they need to be but no higher, with a desire to raise standards over time. Some journals publish a lot of very high quality work. But other things, of lesser "quality", perhaps, also contribute to the forward advance of science and scholarship.

I've found that the journals of large professional societies are high quality, though that may be field dependent.

Giants stand on the shoulders of others, only some of whom are also giants.

If a person wants to publish outstanding papers they need to learn, over time, to do two things, primarily. First, do good research on hard problems. But even finding hard problems that are current solvable is hard in itself. For most of us it helps to have a wide circle of collaborators and to hold a lot of discussions.

The second thing is to learn to write clearly and informatively, especially with difficult material. This is also hard as it is more than a technical skill, requiring some knowledge of the audience.

And then practice, practice, practice. And listen to the feedback you get.

Most of us strive for this (I hope). But whether we achieve it is up to others; our readers.